# I have a GeocoderQueryError and suspect it's an issue with my API management

Tags: django, python-2.7, google-geocoding-api

```
GeocoderQueryError at /search/
Your request was denied.
```

I'm seeing this issue across all versions of my application. That is locally, on staging, and on production. This leads me to believe it's something I've done in the API console since I haven't touched production and only touched the API call on staging. I have been in the API console but have only added IP addresses to "Accept requests from these server IP addresses" input in the credentials tab.

Here is the staging link: [test.translgx.com](http://test.translgx.com/)

You'll only see a 500 page after searching for a ZIP code. I've included the full error report from my local installation at the bottom of the post, I hope this is helpful. If not, let me know and I'll do what I can to get the info needed to solve this.

Full disclosure, I'm a front-end guy and don't have the debugging/diagnostic skills needed to figure this out. I also don't have any back-end dev support available to me until next week. Google's support docs tell me to come here with questions so I'm hoping someone here shows mercy and points me in the right direction.

I should also note that the API key I see in production doesn't match any key in my console.

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/?address=94133&distance=zip&truck=

Django Version: 1.9.4
Python Version: 2.7.11
Installed Applications:
('django_pdb',
 u'django.contrib.auth',
 u'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 u'django.contrib.sessions',
 u'django.contrib.sites',
 u'django.contrib.messages',
 u'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 u'django.contrib.admin',
 u'django.contrib.gis',
 u'crispy_forms',
 u'post_office',
 u'widget_tweaks',
 u'captcha',
 u'geoposition',
 u'cities_light',
 u'templatetag_handlebars',
 u'trucking_directory.common.apps.CommonConfig',
 'debug_toolbar',
 'django_extensions')
Installed Middleware:
(u'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 u'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 u'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 u'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 u'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 u'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
 'django_pdb.middleware.PdbMiddleware')



Traceback:

File "/Users/me/Envs/tlx-d/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response 149.
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/me/Envs/tlx-d/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response 147.
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/me/Envs/tlx-d/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in inner 184.
return func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/me/Envs/tlx-d/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view 68. 
return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/me/Envs/tlx-d/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch 88. 
return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/me/Sites/_app/trucking-directory/trucking_directory/common/views.py" in get 261.
self.form.is_valid()

File "/Users/me/Envs/tlx-d/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in is_valid 161.
return self.is_bound and not self.errors

File "/Users/me/Envs/tlx-d/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in errors 153.
self.full_clean()

File "/Users/me/Envs/tlx-d/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in full_clean 362.
self._clean_fields()

File "/Users/me/Envs/tlx-d/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in _clean_fields 383.
value = getattr(self, 'clean_%s' % name)()

File "/Users/me/Sites/_app/trucking-directory/trucking_directory/common/forms.py" in clean_address 218.
locations = _get_location(data, False)

File "/Users/me/Sites/_app/trucking-directory/trucking_directory/common/forms.py" in _get_location 38. 
location = g.geocode(address, exactly_one=one)

File "/Users/me/Envs/tlx-d/lib/python2.7/site-packages/geopy/geocoders/googlev3.py" in geocode 217.
self._call_geocoder(url, timeout=timeout), exactly_one

File "/Users/me/Envs/tlx-d/lib/python2.7/site-packages/geopy/geocoders/googlev3.py" in _parse_json 338.
self._check_status(page.get('status'))

File "/Users/me/Envs/tlx-d/lib/python2.7/site-packages/geopy/geocoders/googlev3.py" in _check_status 369.
'Your request was denied.'

Exception Type: GeocoderQueryError at /search/
Exception Value: Your request was denied.
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to add an API key. If you don't have one, try the **GET A KEY** in the top-left corner of the [Geocoding API guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro). The, I think this code should work (borrowed from [here](https://github.com/geopy/geopy/issues/171)):

```
from geopy.geocoders import GoogleV3
point = '51.523910, -0.158578'
geocoder = GoogleV3(api_key=YOUR_API_KEY)
address = geolocator.reverse(point)
```